# Environment variables not passed to program

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, environment-variables, macos

The setup I have is a bit convoluted but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I'm on macOS, and I use [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) as my hotkey daemon. It's basically a program that lets me assign keyboard shortcuts to shell commands.

One of the key bindings executes the following command

```
/Applications/Alacritty.app/Contents/MacOS/alacritty -e lf
```

alacritty is my terminal, and this command opens a new terminal window with [lf](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf), a terminal based file manager, already running.

The editor used by `lf` is the one specified by the `EDITOR` environment variable, and it defaults to vim if that's not assigned.

Now here's the problem: if I just run `lf` from my interactive shell, the `EDITOR` variable, which I defined and exported in my `.zshrc`, is recognized correctly by `lf`. If instead I launch `lf` with the key binding, the `EDITOR` is not seen and I have to use the default one.

If I change the command assigned to the key binding to

```
EDITOR=nvim /Applications/Alacritty.app/Contents/MacOS/alacritty -e lf
```

then the `EDITOR` variable is recognized, but I don't want to do this for all the other environment variables I want to pass to `lf`.

How can I correctly forward the variables defined and exported in my `.zshrc` to the `lf` instance launched by a key binding?

Comment: How do you start the hotkey daemon? Do you start it from a `zsh` that has executed your `.zshrc`? **Please answer this in your question.**  According to http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html, `.zshrc` is sourced in interactive shells only. If the daemon is started from a non-interactive `zsh` you might have to define `EDITOR` in `.zshenv`. If it is started from a different shell, you might have to use some other startup file.

Comment: Defining and exporting the variables in `/etc/zshenv` seems to work.